# menu disappears when turning on debug after upgrade to 5.48.2

Tags: menu, debug

Enabling Debug, save, menu goes away.  Disable debug menu comes back.  I've looked at the resource urls, Directories, checked the file permissions and ownership.  I don't find anything in any log.

This is in a development environment.  I'm pretty sure turning on debug prior to the upgrade worked but I can't swear to it.

This was an upgrade from 5.38.1 and I did install a number of the new form extensions.

What/where should I look further?

Comment: could it be theme related?

Comment: Anything in your browser console? Possibly some javascript breakage.